# How to shorten Excel OR function for many conditions?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

As shown in the data, I want to determine whether a student passed (failing if s/he gets less than 40% in any subject). I can do this using many `OR`'s inside `IF`.
[image: Data]

My formula: `=if(or(b3/b$2<0.4,c3/c$2<0.4, d3/d$2<0.4),"NO","YES")`

Can I shorten the formula anyway?

Something like this:

`=if(or((B3:D3)/(B$2:D$2)<0.4),"NO", "YES")`

Thanks

Comment: You could probably remove the `IF(..., "NO", "YES")` bit and have the cell instead display Excel's boolean values "TRUE" "FALSE". This would be just as readable but would also be easier to process: e.g. how many students have passed could be calculated with `SUM()`

Comment: You tagged Excel, but in Excel your 'something like' formula is valid (in older versions require entered with 'ctrl+shift+enter'). Excel is not Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(MIN(B3:D3/$B$2:$D$2)<0.4,"NO","YES")
```

*or*

```
=IF(OR(B3:D3/$B$2:$D$2<0.4),"NO","YES")
```

*and fill down*

If you have `365` you can enter a single formula:

```
E3: =BYROW(B3:D5,LAMBDA(arr,IF(OR(arr/B2:D2<0.4),"NO","YES")))
```

and the results will `SPILL` down

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMahmud I don't know what that means. Works fine here. What about your setup did you not mention? What do you mean by doesn't work? Computer crashes ?error message? Something else?

Comment: @AbdullahAlMahmud If you have an earlier version of Excel than 365, which you did not mention, you will need to enter this as an **array formula**. Hold down `ctrl` + `shift` while hitting `enter`. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar. If you are using Sheets, do the same thing or use `=ArrayFormula(IF(OR(B3:D3/$B$2:$D$2<0.4),"NO","YES"))`

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld thank you! This works exactly as wanted.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMahmud Glad to help. Since my answer seems to be what you require, kindly mark it as Accepted.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @RonRosenfeldHappily did

Answer (score 1):

Pick out the `MIN()` value and test for your limit.

Comment: In this case, the tests seem to be "out of" different numbers of possible marks, so the min mark might not be the min %.